# why apache mesos masters servers switching very fast

Tags: mesos

I have an mesos cluster environment where I have connected two mesos masters. Both the mesos masters are mentioned in the zookeeper. As expected when one master goes down then zookeeper should elect another master from the cluster, but in my case I can see even both my masters servers are running but still its switching very fast may be once in a 5 mins. I don't know if this is normal.

I am using linux Mint, and downloaded mesos from mesosphere library.

Comment: What is the code you are running? You can edit your question to add this information.

Comment: I am not running any code or application. i just have configured mesos master cluster mentioned in the mesosphere documentation. I am seeing this in 5050 port of the local machine's browser.

Comment: What value did you use for the quorum param? Maybe also share the rest of your configuration.

Comment: I am using 2 mesos masters and in zookeeper i have used quorum value as 1. after i have installed mesos from mesosphere, i could not run zookeeper as a service. it said unrecognized service so i have to separately down load zookeeper and start them manually. do you think that could cause a problem?

Comment: I've started ZooKeeper manually all the time. As long as things are configured correctly, it should work. You should edit your original post and include your configuration.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that the quorum in your case is not a majority of masters. Check the [documentation](http://mesos.apache.org/documentation/latest/configuration/) for the  `--quorum` flag. I would suggest you either go for a simple setup with a single master or, if you want to try out the [HA mode](http://mesos.apache.org/documentation/latest/high-availability/), setup 3 masters and set `quorum` to 2. A rule of thumb is `2q - 1` masters for quorum `q`.